# Request blocked if it is sent by node,js axios

Tags: node.js, axios, user-agent, http-status-code-403

I am using axios and a API (cowin api https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin/cowin-public-v2) which has strong kind of protection against the web requests.
When I was getting error 403 on my dev machine (Windows) then, I solve it by just adding a header 'User-Agent'.
When I have deployed it to heroku I am still getting the same error.

```js
 const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
     },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a fake user-agent in your headers can help with this problem, but there are other variables you may want to consider.

For example, if you are making multiple HTTP requests you may want to have multiple fake user-agents to and then randomize the user-agent for every request made. This can help limit the changes of your scraper being detected.

If that still doesn't work you may want to consider optimizing your headers further. Other than sending HTTP requests with a randomized user-agent, you can further imitate a browser's request Headers by adding more Headers than just the "user-agent"- then ensuring that the user-agent that is selected is consistent with the information sent from the rest of the headers.
You can check out [here](https://scrapeops.io/web-scraping-playbook/web-scraping-guide-header-user-agents/) for more information.

On the site it will not only provide information on how to optimize your headers consistently with the user-agent, but also provide more solutions in case the above mentioned still was unsuccessful.

In my situation, it was the case that I had to bypass cloudflare. You can determine if this is your situation as well if you log your error to the terminal and then check if under the "server" key it says "cloudflare". In which case you can use [this](https://scrapeops.io/web-scraping-playbook/how-to-bypass-cloudflare/) documentation for further assistance.